# How can I stream sound from the microphone in mp3 format?

Tags: mp3, vlc, naudio, rtp, libvlc

I need a software that can stream audio with mp3 format.The audio will come from the microphone at the same time.

I have a software that can stream sound with **alaw** and **ulaw** codecs. 
And I have an another program that can stream recorded **mp3 file**. Not capture from the microphone.

**I can make stream with VLC.Dotnet wrapper but I didn't succeed with directshow.(namely microphone)**

Here my Vlc.Dotnet code;

```
myVlcControl.Play("dshow://");
myVlcControl.Play(new Uri("dshow://"));
```

It **did not work** with this codes. I don't know what causes the problem.

My second software can stream sound that captures form microphone in real time. But its codec format is alaw not mp3. I did not find any converter that convert linear to mp3 file. I find a converter that convert linear to alaw. this is the link [Linear to Alaw Codec](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14237/Using-the-G-standard)
I know the LAME and NAudio but it converts wav file to mp3. I need linear to mp3(like in the link)

I am very confused. I really do not know which way to go.
1. Find a codec linear to mp3 (It's very complicated) ?
2. Learn VLC direct Show usage on .NET ?

Thank you so much in advance.

*VLC.DotNet, axVLCPlugin21, LAME, ffmpeg....

Comment: Did you take a look at NAudio?

Comment: You would have to create a memorystream which is a byte[] and convert it to mp3 via NAudio

Comment: I've successfully finished. I 've chosen the VLC. dotnet wrapper and compiled with 32 bit. The problem is about VLC.Dotnet can not successfully compile with 64 bit. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as  I've successfully solved this problem with VLC.Dotnet wrapper. The problem is compiling with x64 architectural. When I was compiled with x86 architectural, The problem solved.